# Rename CVS module without losing history

Tags: module, rename, cvs

I have a CVS module named **OldProjectName**.

I need to rename it to **NewProjectName**.

I don't want to lose the history of the files, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the server, you should be able to just rename the folder for the module in the cvs root. The history will be preserved because it's all stored in all the directories under that top level folder.

Note that if you do this, you will invalidate any existing working copies and will have to check out the project again.

If you don't have access to the server then there is no way that I know of to achieve what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just found this way to solve it, it preserves history and probably without any error.

```
$ mv old new
$ cvs remove old
$ cvs add new
$ cvs commit -m "Renamed old to new" old new
```

Comment: This affects a single file. The question is about the entire CVS module.